# Liferay + Ext Js : Setting up Layout

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I just started to use Liferay and I want to develop a portlet using Ext JS from sensha.
I think (from the search I made)the problem is that there is a conflit between liferay CSS and Ext CSS but still not found any solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYU5b.png

Anyone knows how to fix this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard to discover if the CSS files really get into the way of each other. Just inspect your panel elements' CSS and see what rules get applied (you are searching particularly ones that affect position, e.g. top/left/margin...).

If it's Ext's styles affecting Liferay's styles, then you can just re-generate ext-all.css file using a different prefix (the default is "*x-*"). Please provide more details when you do some investigation.

Comment: I've discovered the problem. Thanks

Comment: If you think that your problem is common, it's worth sharing the solution with others...